# WCF Service Stops responding

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

IIS 10, Server 2016
Setup, 3 identical VMs, loadbalanced with haproxy service wcf service.

Problem: 
After a short period of time 1 of the 3 servers will stop responding to WCF calls. The method in question returns a simple static string.

With WCF tracing enabled I can see when things are working a total of 4 traces associated to each message:

- TransportReceive
- ServiceLevelReceiveRequest
- ServiceLevelSendReply
- TransportSend

[image: Working]

However, after a period of time 1 of the 3 servers just stops responding, and I see this in the message tracing:

- TransportReceive

I never see any of the other messages. I'm not getting any errors on the server (in event logs or in the wcf tracing)

[image: Not Working]

To make this more odd, if I remove this server from the pool, it starts working. Once I add the server back to the pool it breaks again a short time later.

I've scoured google looking for good documentation on wcf tracing and how to figure out why this method is apparently not being executed by wcf, but I'm coming up empty in my searches.

Why is my method not executing, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any help from event viewer?

Comment: @Hameed - Nadda - nothing in event logs or in application logs. The request just dies in WCF.